# VS2017 on Windows with iOS SDK 11.2.1.0 & Mac with XCode 9.2 Beta

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

Even with all lastest tools installed on Both Visual studio (on windows) and XCode on Mac, I am receiving following error when tried to connect from visual studio 2017 through Xamarin agent. Any hint how to solve it?

"The installed Xamarin.iOS (version not specified) on the Mac 192.168.186.128 is not compatible with the local Xamarin.iOS (version 11.2.1.0). Please select a new server or install the correct Xamarin.iOS versions.[image: Windows 10 & Mac Sierra 10.12.6]

Comment: What version of `Xamarin.iOS` is installed on the Mac?

Comment: update `Xamarin.iOS on Mac`  to the lastest version . (keep the  same as xamarin.ios on Windows)

Comment: @ColeXia precisely, how to do that? Xamarin.iOS on windows is latest and I have installed XCode 9.2 latest on Mac.

Comment: Do you install visual studio on mac or not?

Comment: No. do you also think it is required?

Comment: Yes, It is required , refer to https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/#System_Requirements

Comment: Yes, after VS 2017 installation on Mac, its all working fine now!

Comment: @ColeXia Thanks to you too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Even with all lastest tools installed on Both Visual studio (on windows) and XCode on Mac

In order to build Xamarin.iOS apps, Xamarin Tools and SDKs are needed on the Mac, too. You should have [Visual Studio for Mac](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/) installed, it comes with all the necessary tools and SDKs.

If Xamarin is outdated on your Mac (disregarding of the Xcode version) you will see the message that Xamarin.iOS is outdated. Please follow [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/update) to update your Xamarin components. (Anyway, avoid the beta channel and stick to stable unless you have a good reason not to.)

Comment: I don't want to build iOS apps on Mac, I just need to test the iOS app built  using VS 2017 installed on Windows. Isn't this a valid use-case?

Comment: I think there is a mismatch of the understanding of the word *build* (or *built*) between the two of us. In order to avoid misunderstandings I'll use compile for now. You cannot compile an iOS app without a Mac. The VS components of Xamarin can do this for you via SSH, but you'll need some components installed on the Mac, too.

Comment: so let me install VS 2017 on Mac and see.

Comment: Ok, after installing VS 2017 on Mac, I was able to run the simulator. Thanks!

Comment: @PavanGR Glad to hear that I've been able to help.

Comment: So if my mac os can only be as high as 10.12.6; does that mean I won't be able to build ios 11 apps which require higher versions of sdk/xcode that are only available on mac os 10.13.x? Is ios backward compatible? If my app is built against ios 10, can it still run on a phone running ios 11?